# Как правильно получить собственную версию репозитория с GitHub?

Tags: git, github

У меня есть следующая задача: На GitHub есть репозиторий. Я создаю проект и выкачиваю его. После этого мне надо отвязаться от этого репозитория и создать новый, залить его на GitHub, и чтоб он уже отслеживал изменения, и на него делать коммиты. Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой и удобный способ — сделать собственный форк оригинального репозитория и клонировать его. Более того, этот способ правильный с точки зрения github-flow, методологии организации совместной работы с помощью git/github. Даже если пока что это вам не нужно, может пригодиться потом.

При таком варианте у вас появится удобный инструмент, чтобы:

1. Добавлять новые изменения из оригинального репозитория. Это довольно полезно, если там идет активная работа и добавляются новые фичи.
2. [Предложить влить собственные изменения в оригинальный репозиторий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505731/181472).

Форк делается так:

1. Заходите на страницу интересующего репозитория
2. Жмете на кнопку <kbd>fork</kbd>:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. После краткого ожидания на вашей странице в GitHub появляется копия репозитория - форк. Там есть текстовое поле, из которого вы можете скопировать адрес для клонирования:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. На своей рабочей машине выполняете команду (строку подставьте из своего репозитория):

   ```
   git clone git@github.com:username/project.git
   ```

   Либо, если вы сначала клонировали чужой репозиторий, вам нужно перенастроить свой репозиторий на свой.

   ```
   git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/project.git
   ```

   Либо так, если вы хотите подключить репозиторий как субмодуль в уже существующий и версионируемый проект (подходит для разных зависимостей и компонент вашего проекта):

   ```
   git submodule add git@github.com:username/project.git path/to/submodule
   ```

   Здесь `path/to/submodule` - путь к директории, в которой будет располагаться содержимое репозитория, подключенного как субмодуль.

Теперь у вас есть локальная копия репозитория. Она уже настроена на pull/push в вашу копию на GitHub.

Ещё пара моментов:

> чтоб он уже отслеживал изменения

Изменения всегда отслеживает ваш локальный репозиторий. В удаленный на GitHub никогда не передаются файлы в таком виде, как они лежат у вас на жестком диске и он не может знать об изменениях, которые вы сделали локально, но не запушили.

> и на него делать комментарии

Не путайте, это называется «коммиты», "commit". Тут можно почитать об этом и найти пару хороших ссылок: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-commit/info

Answer (score 1):

1. Для начала добавляем новый удаленный репозиторий:

   ```
   git remote add new-origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git
   ```
2. Делаем  `push` в него:

   ```
   git push --all new-origin
   ```

> *Если требуется полностью отвязаться от старого репозитория:*
>
> 1. Удаляем старый репозиторий:
>
>    ```
>    git remote rm origin
>    ```
> 2. Переименовываем новый репозиторий:
>
>    ```
>    git remote rename new-origin origin
>    ```