# git работа с чужими репозиториями

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-branch, git-push

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как лучше поступить?

У меня есть репозиторий, с которым я активно работаю. Иногда я использую чужие библиотеки, расположенные на *GitH*ub. Я хочу иметь возможность изменять части этих библиотек и иметь возможность скачивать новые версии и обьединять с моей работой. Как это лучше делать? Я вот пробовал субмодули, но как я понял, к ним нужно еще репозиторий заводить кроме репозитория меинтейнера.

Comment: Субмодули в отдельных репозитариях, это норма.

Comment: Вам нужен форк: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/478040/181472. Я там добавил инструкцию по подключению форка субмодулем - для различных зависимостей вашего проекта это предпочтительный способ.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub позволяет легко делать форки чужих репозиториев. Сделайте копию библиотеки себе и используйте как субмодуль.